# How to override the code generation for Generate > Class in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have read [Why are my classes private by default in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913836/why-are-my-classes-private-by-default-in-visual-studio) and succcessfully used the advice given. Now if I invoke Add > New Item, > Class (or just Add > Class), I get the empty class created the way I want it (as a Public class, amongst other things).

However, if within my code I write the name of a non-existent class and then I right-click on it and invoke Generate > Class then the code that this generates is the old default code for a class  -  without my modifications.  In other words, it appears that Generate > Class does *not* use the Class.zip template that is used when you do Add > New Item, > Class (or just Add > Class).

Can anyone tell me where the template (or other mechanism) for the code generated by Generate > Class *is* located?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a standard VS2010 feature.  Document what add-on you use, like Resharper.

Comment: I don't have any add-ons, even tried running Visual Studio 2010 in safe mode and this feature is still there. Don't know how that's not standard. Unfortunate that nobody had an answer.